# Значение переменной выпадает за span

Tags: php

Есть следующий код.

```
function display_user_personage() {
    $args = array(
        'field'   => 3,
    );
    echo '<span>' . bp_profile_field_data( $args ) . '</span>';
}
```

Функция возвращает текстовое значение. Но вместо того чтобы поместить его внутрь span, выбрасывает его.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно функция `bp_profile_field_data` не возвращает значение, а сразу выводит значение на экран.

Comment: @u_mulder Да. Вы были правы. Нужно было привязаться к функции bp_пуе_profile_field_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция bp_profile_field_data не возвращает значение а сразу выводит его. Правильным было использовать  `bp_get_profile_field_data`.

Comment: @u_mulder njxyj) 

(шутка)